# prompt user while creating maven project using archetype

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

We have created maven archetype for users to generate project. Now we want a certain archetype property to be set using the user input. Can somebody point out a way by which we can prompt the user for input during project generation and use the input to set the property?

Answer (score 1):

Make use of a property file, visit http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/examples/create-with-property-file.html to see how this works.